# how to get a data templates to display data in columns

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a data template in a listbox that is dynamically creating 6 labels.  It displays the content for those labels in one row.  How would I get the data template to list the data in 3 columns of 2 rows?  So, if I added 9 dynamic labels, it would be arrange it as 3 columns of 3 rows.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLayoutsOC, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Margin="0">
             <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <Label Content="{Binding AvailableLayoutLabel}"/> 
                      </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>      
   </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but don't forget to have a `SelectedLayoutLabel` binding for the selection:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLayoutsOC}"
             Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLayoutLabel}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding AvailableLayoutLabel}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```